# How to remove the directory a symbolic link links to plus the symbolic link?

Tags: shell, symlink, rm

Say `a` is a symbolic link to `b`. I am looking for a simple command to remove both `a` and `b` at once that does not require me to know about `b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently I am not allowed to comment, so here as an answer:
Since `a` is the link,
we need the recursive option on the dereferenced directory...

```
rm -rf "$(readlink -f "a")"; rm -f "a"
```

Comment: And it is not a bad answer. Although you could detail more, what it does and how.

Comment: Welcome to unix.se! Yours is an answer and thus accepted as such. So in a way it's a good thing you are not allowed to comment - [yet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) ‎

Answer (score 2):

My current solution is

```
rm -rf "$(readlink -f "a")"; rm -f "a"
```

But maybe there's something easier?

Comment: Nothing easier, you need to remove the symlink and the directory separately. I strongly urge you to use `readlink -f` there, mainly because if `a` actually has directory components (`foo/bar`), `$(readlink a)` is relative to the location where the link is (`foo`). And don't forget to double quote all variable and command substitutions. Also, you don't need `-r` to remove a symbolic link. Thus: `rm -f "$(readlink -f "a")"; rm -rf "a"`

Comment: @Gilles: good points, edited them in, thank you

Comment: @Gilles: [As Cruisen just noticed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14082/23408#394212) (after six years), you put the `r` on the wrong command.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the note, I never noticed that...

Answer (score 1):

Some systems will dereference the symlink when you add a trailing slash (at least if the symlink points to a directory):

```
mkdir -p b/c && touch b/c/foo && ln -s b/c a

rm -rf a/ && rm -f a
# removed "b/c" and "a"
```

The POSIX standard has changed a bit (see Pathname Resolution in [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) vs. [IEEE Std 1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12)), but it seems like the behavior for a pathname with a trailing slash and a final pathname components that is a symlink is (mostly) the same: the symlink is resolved.

Not all systems implement this behavior though (see comment by Gilles).

Comment: This doesn't work on many systems. GNU coreutils 8.5 gets confused as to the nature of `a/` (``rm: cannot remove `a': Not a directory``), and if you explicitly specify `a/.` it understandably can't cope (``rm: cannot remove directory: `a/.'``). OpenBSD just treats `a/` like `a` (`rm -r a/` removes the symlink).

Comment: @Gilles: (changed “many” to “some”); it is unfortunate that *readlink(1)* is also not portable (especially its options).